# How to delete objects and thread instances in QCoreApplication destructor

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, qt

```
  //my_class.h

  void My_class::My_Class(){

     my_ip=...
     my_port=...
  };

  void Data_Send_Func(){

 // send data over tcp;

 }

  void My_Class::~My_Class(){

   cout<<"Delete objects"<<endl;

  }

  void My_Class::process(){

     QTimer my_timer;
     my_timer->setInterval(30);
     connect(my_timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(Data_Send_Func()));
     connect(this,SIGNAL(destroyed()),mytimer,SLOT(deleteLater));
  }


  //my_application.cpp
  My_application::My_application:QCoreApplication{

     my_class=new My_Class();

     QThread thread=new QThread();

     my_class->moveToThread(thread);

     connect(thread,SIGNAL(started()),my_class,SLOT(process())) ;

     connect(my_class,SIGNAL(finished()),thread,SLOT(quit())) ;

     connect(thread,SIGNAL(finished()),thread,SLOT(deletelater())) ;

     connect(my_class,SIGNAL(finished()),my_class,SLOT(deletelater())) ;        

 }

  //my_application.h

 struct Exit_App{

    Exit_App(){

     signal(SIGINT,&Exit_App::Exit_F); 
     signal(SIGTERM,&Exit_App::Exit_F); 
     signal(SIGBREAK,&Exit_App::Exit_F);  

   }
     static void Exit_F(int sig){

       cout<<"Exiting App"<<endl;

       QCoreApplication::exit(0);
     }
 }


 int main(argc,char* argv[]){

     Exit_App app;
     My_application a(arcg,argv);
     return a.exec();

 }
```

So when I close my program I want to delete the objects in My_Class destructor.

I dont want to emit fnished signal in application so I want to delete the my_class object and thread in My_application destructor.

```
   My_application::~My_application{
   if (my_class->thread()) {

     connect(my_class, SIGNAL(destroyed()), thread, SLOT(quit());

     my_class->deleteLater();

  } else {

     delete my_class; // It's a threadless object, we can delete it
    thread->quit();
     }
    thread->wait();

 }
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Does the program crash, or does it print some error message while executing the destructor, or does it misbehave in some other way?

Comment: @Frank I put some debug code in the entry and exit to destructor.The entry debug string is printed but exit is never

Comment: @barp You need to show complete self-contained test case. Your constructor isn't called either, BTW, but that's because you defined the wrong constructor!

Comment: @kuba i am editing and posting the destructor of my_class.I tested that your code calls my_class->deletelater().But then the destructor does not work.

Comment: @barp You must post a [single-file, complete, self contained example that illustrates the problem](http://www.sscce.org). Until you do so, the question doesn't have enough information to help diagnose the problem. I've put your (fixed to get it to compile) code into a simple example and it works, so whatever you've posted is not where the problem is. Really.

Comment: @barp I can clean up your example for you, but it will be something that works and the question immediately becomes up for closing since the problem doesn't reproduce :)

Comment: @kuba ok i will edit and write the code

Answer (score 4):

A `QObject` cannot be deleted from any thread but the one it's in, unless it is thread less (due to its thread having finished). The following must hold:

```
Q_ASSERT(!object->thread() || object->thread() == QThread::currentThread());
delete object;
```

In case of an object that has a thread, you need to invoke the object's `deleteLater` method. The deletion will be done within the thread's event loop. When the object is deleted, it's time to finish the thread. So:

```
if (my_class->thread()) {
  connect(my_class, SIGNAL(destroyed()), thread, SLOT(quit());
  my_class->deleteLater();
} else {
  delete my_class; // It's a threadless object, we can delete it
  thread->quit();
}
thread->wait();
```

Note that it's OK to call `quit()` and `wait()` on a thread that is finished. It is redundant to check for a running thread like you do.

Comment: .I tried it but id does not enter my_class destructor